# Which the other timeseries database apart from kdb can be used

Tags: kdb

What are the different/best database to be used apart from KDB for timeseries.
- should be a freeware
- can handle 50GB or more with faster retrieval of selective data

Comment: Similar info here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/20625/performance-of-open-source-time-series-database-for-financial-market-data

Comment: Note that Kx do have free versions of kdb (even 64bit) for non-commercial use